# How to filter list when use FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-futurebuilder

I use FutureBuilder in IndexedListView to show a phonebook list,

```
Widget _buildBody(context) {
  String url = api_url_phonebook;
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          onTap: () => onTextChanged(_controller.text),
          ...
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: IndexedListView(
            100.0,
            _getData(context, url),
            ...
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Future<Either<ResponseError, List<dynamic>>> _getData(context, url) {
  final result = RequestApi(url).fetchList();
  return result;
}

onSearchTextChanged(String text) {
  ...
}
```

Now I want filter this phonebook when I input text in TextField, what can I do?

Comment: your build method calls the API every time it's built?

Comment: Can you put the code of the whole page? Declare the fetched list results as a local variable in your parent widget. Fetch the data during initState and filter the local List instead of fetching it everytime

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the Delegate pattern to do that.

Make a class like the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:mywallet/model/user_account.dart';
import 'package:mywallet/ui/account_item.dart';

class AccountListSearch extends SearchDelegate {
  final List<UserAccount> newItems;
  String selectedResult = '';
  AccountListSearch(this.newItems);

  bool _match(UserAccount account, String text) {
    return account.name.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()) ||
        account.user.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase());
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) => [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: () {
            query = '';
          },
        ),
      ];

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) => IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      );

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
      child: Text(selectedResult),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    var suggestionList = <UserAccount>[];
    query.isEmpty
        ? suggestionList = newItems
        : suggestionList.addAll(
            newItems.where((item) {
              return _match(item, query);
            }),
          );
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => AccountItem(
        account: suggestionList[index],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Copy and paste the AccountListSearch class, only change the UserAccount class with your data class ( PhoneBook Item), and change the AccountItem stateless widget with your Widget used to display your PhoneBook item ( something like class PhoneBookItemWidget extends StatelessWidget......)

Then in the main page like this class:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AccountCubit, AccountState>(
      builder: (_, state) {
        var currentState = state;
        if (currentState is InitializedState) {
          var accounts = currentState.userAccounts;
          return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('All Accounts'),
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      showSearch(
                          context: context,
                          delegate: AccountListSearch(accounts));
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              drawer: AppDrawer(),
              body:    
              ListView.builder(
                       itemCount: accounts.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, counter) => AccountItem(
                                               account: accounts[counter],
                                               )
....
}
```

As you can see, the  'magic' is in the method :

```
showSearch( context: context,  delegate: AccountListSearch(accounts));
```

The method showSearch(...) is inherited from StatelessWidget and make all the work for you.

I used the Bloc pattern, but it is not important right now, only to tell where to find  the list of items, but it is not directly related to your question.

Comment: so there are two places to call AccountItem in your code? one is for initial and another is for search?

Comment: Yes, because when you filter it uses the delegated class

Comment: In fact, you can use the Bloc patern instead of the FutureBuilder to build your widget. You can use a "UnitializedState" and "InitializedState", the first will  run the loading, and you can display a CircularProgressIndicator, and at the end you switch to InitializedState and you can display the widget above.

Comment: At last I got what I need. I didn't use SearchDelegate because it show search box is not in the same page with list.